# How to create index on sub field of json arry in mysql?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, indexing, multivalue

An index can be created on array elements either using multi-value index or index on virtual column. Is it possible to create index on a sub field of the array elements? e.g.

```
create table link
(
    id bigint not null primary key,
...
    left json not null
)
```

structure of column left:

```
[{
  "fieldId": 123, ...
}]
```

Multi-value index: can be created but not used when query

```
ALTER TABLE link ADD INDEX IDX_LEFT_FIELD( (CAST(`left`->'$[*].fieldId' AS unsigned ARRAY)) );
```

Virtual column: can be created but column left_field_id on each row produces value 0 instead of the value of sub field fieldId

```
ALTER TABLE link
ADD COLUMN `left_field_id` bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS (`left`->'$[*].fieldId') Virtual NULL AFTER `left`;
```

I wonder if there is anything wrong in the statements above?

Comment: Provide complete example (the best way as a fiddle).

Comment: The schema of the JSON looks pretty static to me. You should consider not to abuse JSON but use relational means like (lookup and/or linking) tables and columns instead. That would make indexing at least easier too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see the index is used.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d0a5d1432503b6e82dc31845225a92d8)

> | id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | SIMPLE | link | *null* | range | IDX_LEFT_FIELD | IDX_LEFT_FIELD | 9 | *null* | 5 | 100.00 | Using where |

Comment: I test again and the type is also range now.